# Confirm box is blocking/pausing

Tags: angularjs

I have a `ng-click="myFunc(aEntry)"`

And then myFunc is this:

```
    MODULE.myFunc = function(aEntry) {
        aEntry.hilite = true;
        if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) {
            aEntry.hilite = false;
            return;
        }
    };
```

However it wont update the dom to show it highlighted. The confirm box seems to be pausing it. Does anyone know a work around?

Comment: can you elaborate little more or create a fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

It is because `confirm` is a blocking function. I understand you want to have a ui change, but

```
aEntry.hilite = true;
```

is not a UI change. It is a logical change. You probably have an event handler which runs after you have called `confirm`. You need to guarantee that the highlighting ui operation is performed before you call the `confirm`. There are several ways to do it.

The most primitive way is to use `setTimeout` and put your `confirm` call inside it, using a time, which is surely longer than the time you need to wait for the ui handler to be executed.

A slightly better approach is to use `setInterval` until the ui change has occured.

But the best approach would be to pass the `confirm` with a `function` wrapped around it used as a callback for the ui change or to trigger the ui change event before you call `confirm`.